# Add 2 form fields together using JS

Tags: javascript

I am creating a script which included a calculation to add 2 form form fields together and out the result onkeyup

```
<script>
function sum()
{
var w = document.getElementById('amount').value || 0;
var x = document.getElementById('vat').value || 0;
var z=parseInt(w)+parseInt(x);
var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(z).toFixed(2) 
document.getElementById('final').value=twoPlacedFloat;
};   
</script>
```

This is working however it does not add the decimals together, what do I need to change to make it do this?

Example:
Unit Cost (12.00) + VAT (2.40) should total 14.40 however it is showing 14.00?

[image]

Comment: use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`

Comment: And don't bother using parseFloat(z)  - this is already a number

Comment: Excellent - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
var z=parseInt(w)+parseInt(x);
```

to

`var z=parseFloat(w)+parseFloat(x);`

parse int will not include decimals

Answer (score 1):

You need change from parseInt to parseFloat

```
var z=parseFloat(w)+parseFloat(x);
```

```js
var w = 12.2;
var x = 2.4;
var z=parseFloat(w)+parseFloat(x);
var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(z).toFixed(2) 
document.getElementById('final').value=twoPlacedFloat;
```

```html
<input type='text' id='final'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parseFloat() instead of parseInt().

Answer (score 1):

Change this `var z=parseInt(w)+parseInt(x);` to `var z=parseFloat(w)+parseFloat(x);`

```
<script>
function sum()
{
    var w = document.getElementById('amount').value || 0;
    var x = document.getElementById('vat').value || 0;
    var z=parseFloat(w)+parseFloat(x);
    var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(z).toFixed(2) 
    document.getElementById('final').value=twoPlacedFloat;
 };   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description)

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

You can replace parseInt with unary operator or use parseFloat on the value

```js
function sum() {
  var w = document.getElementById('amount').value || 0;
  var x = document.getElementById('vat').value || 0;
  var z = +w + +x;
  var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(z).toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById('final').value = twoPlacedFloat;
};
```

```html
<input id="amount">
<input id="vat">
<input id="final">
<button type="button" onclick="sum()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the string to a number using `+`

`var z= +w + +x;`

```js
const a = "3";
const b = "4.2";

const result = +a + +b;

console.log(result);
```